# take an array of objects and put it in a bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

i am a new when it comes to jquery and javascript but I'm trying learn slowly.What my question is, if i have a json file that looks like

```
   var data=  [{"tasknumber":304030,
   "date":"2012-05-05",
   "operator":"john doe"},
  {"tasknumber":23130,
   "date":"2012-07-07",
   "operator":"john doeeeeeeee"},
   {"tasknumber":233330,
   "date":"2012-08-08",
   "operator":"john doe"}]
```

and i applied .countBy to it from the underscore library to get a array that looks like this

```
{"john doe":2,"john doeeeeeeee":1}
```

so for the next part im using a sample jquery graph outline which i found online

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title:{
            text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
        },
        data: [              
        {
            // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
            type: "column",
            dataPoints: [
                { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
                { label: "orange", y: 15  },
                { label: "banana", y: 25  },
                { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
                { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried a couple ways to call my new array within this part of the code

```
data: [              
        {
            // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
            type: "column",
            dataPoints: [
                //insert here
            ]
        }
        ]
```

but i only get blank screens and undefine when i try and open it.does anyone have any guidance for me on how to call my array within the datapoints?

my data is in a different file called task.json and i gotta call it using

```
var input=require('./task.json');
const _ = require(`underscore`);
var names=_.countBy(input,'operator');
```

Comment: which array you want to call within the datapoint? `names?`

Comment: Declare a new variable(say. dps) as an array outside of **CanvasJS.chart** function. Fill that array with data, that you want to show on graph. The data should be in appropriate format as instructed in CanvasJS library. Then, assign that var (dps) to dataPoints inside **CanvasJS.chart**  function. (eg: dataPoints: dps).

Comment: Yea i wanna call names within my datapoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say, your JSON object is stored in some variable(eg: myObject).

```
var myObject = {"john doe":2,"john doeeeeeeee":1};
```

Declare a variable to store dataPoints from your JSON and push dataPoints into your array.

```
var dps = [];
for(var element in myObject) {
    dps.push({label: element, y: myObject[element]});
}
```

Once you have done this, assign this variable (dps) to *dataPoints* of CanvasJS chart.

```
data: [
    type: "column",
    dataPoints: dps
]
```

You can see a working example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8k1m5k5/).